# String Parsing Objective C

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

I want to parse and get the contents within the braces, which actually is as follows.

```
-(void)testfunction
{
   //do something
   integer myVal = 0;
   NSString *testString = @"Test";

   myVal = [someObject test];
   if(myVal >10)
   {
       NSLog(@"Test Succeed");
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"Test Succeed");
       if(testString)
       {
            NSLog("Still");
       }
    }  
}
```

I am expecting the output as all the text in the testFunction.

Is there a simpler logic to parse?

I am using NSString and developing for MAC OS and not iPhone.

Regards,
Nirav

Comment: I suggest you try to search for compiler tutorials, and learn how parsing code works in a compiler.

Comment: I know about the compilers ! Was thinking if there is a simpler solution for Mac-OS or objective C

Comment: Should it be able to handle comments, strings etc that can include `{}`? then you probably need a proper parser somehow. If the functions always start with `{}` as first character in the line then you might get away with some regex/substring hack. What will it be used for?

Comment: Currently I am planning only for the functions without comments etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is build a program that recognizes the start of a function, and reads it until it reaches the closing brace, basically what a compiler does.

The simplest way is probably to use a regular expression to find the function header, and then read line by line (or char by char) counting the opening and closing braces. Remember that the code you read may not always be formatted well, and the closing brace can actually be in the middle of a line with code and/or comments before and after.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I have almost implemented the same thing. I am counting the opening and closing braces. Thanks any ways.

Answer (score 1):

The basic building block for parsing NSStrings is the [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html) class.

More basic is plain C-style `strtok()`.